# Create a Shared Object in Red5 Server with Java but without Actionscript or Flex technology

Tags: java, red5, shared-objects

I'm looking for a way to create a Remote Shared Object in Red5 Server (installed on a server machine) only using Java technology. The shared object can be any thing (simpler is better) because my purpose is just a feasibility study. The problem is that I am a novice in Java and I'm having a hard time .. On Internet there are in fact many tutorials that build applications on Red5, but using Actionscript etc..
Can anyone give me some advice to realize a mini project in Eclipse to create and modify the shared object? Thank you very much and sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 0):

I've build a RTMPClient for doing some load tests recently:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/src/org/apache/openmeetings/test/rtmp/LoadTestRtmpClient.java

It will only establish the RTMP connection and do some remote calls. For ceating a shared object you will probably need to extend the RTMPClient library.

Sebastian

Comment: First of all many thanks for the help!          
From what I see, you practically have created the class LoadTestRtmpClient that extends RtmpClient (import org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPClient from the file red5.jar) Now I have to do 2 questions that will make you realize how dummy I'm with java :)         
1) Unlike the code that I found [here](http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/client/trunk/test/org/red5/client/ClientTest.java?r=4344) (where the parameters for the connection to the server are explicitly declared) where do you set the IP address to connect to Red5 server?

Comment: 2) In Eclipse I create the Java project, add the package org.apache.openmeetings.test.rtmp, then the class LoadTestRtmpClient. I import the external jar and finally I paste your code in the class (I'm writing all the steps in case I'm doing some mistake). When I run the project as Java application, Eclipse searches the main types and then I choose ClientTest - org.red5.client. These steps are correct? Of course then I got errors because I have no locally red5 server active..

Comment: If you have issues in running the code you propably need more libraries then just the red5.jar. Our project is probably not the best example as it has a lot of libraries included.